# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Item' accepts this number of arguments

Tags: sql, vb.net-2010

Making a small page that calls a SQL stored Proc with only one parameter, which the user would enter in a text box. In declaring that parameter, it is giving me the error above. Can anyone assist? The error is on the CMD.Parameters line..

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("daily_revenue_rerun")
    CMD.Parameters("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).value = TextBox1.Text
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=azda-sql0;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Sql@dm!n;Initial Catalog=RevenueTrakSQL"
    CMD.Connection = connection
    CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)
    Dim DS As DataSet
    Adapter.Fill(DS)
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks for any assistance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your parameter binding. What I can see is that your stored proc `daily_revenue_rerun` expects a `DATETIME` datatype variable whereas you are passing a string

```
CMD.Parameters("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).value = TextBox1.Text
```